Sum over $n$ cancels out?
In the proof of Lemma 10.2 of this paper, it says (near the end of the proof):

Summing over $n$ we find
\begin{align}\sum_n\mathbb{P}(A_n) &\le C_1\sum^q_{i=1}\mathbb{E}\Big[\sum_ne^{\lambda (n+1)}\mathbb{1}_{e^{\lambda n}<\varepsilon^{-2}|\xi_i|^2}\Big]
\\[2mm] & \le C_2\sum^q_{i=1}\mathbb{E}\big[\varepsilon^{-2}|\xi_i|^2\big]<\infty\end{align}

My doubts lies in the middle inequality: I understand that for a real $y$, it holds $\mathbb{1}_{y^2\ge1}\le y^2$, hence $$\sum_ne^{\lambda (n+1)}\mathbb{1}_{e^{\lambda n}<\varepsilon^{-2}|\xi_i|^2}\le\sum_ne^{\lambda (n+1)}\frac{\varepsilon^{-2}|\xi_i|^2}{e^{\lambda n}}=\sum_ne^\lambda\varepsilon^{-2}|\xi_i|^2,$$
I understand that the term $e^\lambda$ can be implied in the constant $C_2$, but why does the sum over $n$ cancel out/disappear? Shouldn't it actually diverge?

$e^{\lambda n}<\varepsilon^{-2}|\xi_i|^2$
gives $ n <\lambda^{-1}\ln(\varepsilon^{-2}|\xi_i|^2)$. So
$$\sum_ne^{\lambda (n+1)}1_{e^{\lambda n}<\varepsilon^{-2}|\xi_i|^2}
\le \sum_{n \le \lambda^{-1}\ln(\varepsilon^{-2}|\xi_i|^2)} e^{\lambda} (\varepsilon^{-2}|\xi_i|^2).$$

A-ha, I see. So to say that it is a finite sum. Thank you!

@RiverLi Your comment could (should?) be an answer.

@DavideGiraudo If it is obvious, I think I just stopped there.
